# Enum's toString method and Java good practice

Tags: java, jsf, enums

I'd like to ask about good coding practice in Java. I want to create a enumeratoin of some properties and override `toString()` to use it in the following way (`JSF 1.2` is used in order to retrieve localized message):

```
package ua.com.winforce.casino.email.util;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public enum StatisticItems {
    MESSAGES,
    VIEWS;

    private static String BUNDLE_NAME = "messages";

    public String toString(){
        switch (this) {
        case MESSAGES:
            return getLocalizedMsg("messages.title");
        case VIEWS:
            return getLocalizedMsg("views.title");
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String getLocalizedMsg(String key, Object... arguments) {
        Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
        String resourceString;
        try {
            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale);
            resourceString = bundle.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return key;
        }

        if (arguments == null) {
            return resourceString;
        }
        MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat(resourceString, locale);
        return format.format(arguments);
    }
}
```

My question is about good practice. Is it considered good to put all such methods within a `enum` definition? If not, I'd like to understand why and of course how to do it better.

Comment: Downvoter, why downvote?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to have a `toString()` method complicated enough that it might throw an exception when you are trying to print a debugging message.

Comment: In the future JSF-related questions, you'd better not tag [java]. No one of the answerers took `FacesContext` into account, rendering the both answers technically wrong in JSF context. And, you'd better post code review requests at codereview.se, not at SO. Or at least eliminate subjectiveness/argumentativeness (including words like "best practice") from the question. For the real answer, do a search here using the three simple keywords "jsf", "enum" "localization". I've answered this kind of question before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points to be made here:

1. If the default case (returning null in your code) is a runtime error, then using a `switch` is kind of error prone. There are two better alternatives in my opinion:

   1. Use a field `localizationKey`, initialized in the constructor of the enum instances, and refer to this key in the `toString` method
   2. Or, (for more complicated cases) make the `toString` abstract and force each instance to override with proper implementation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968075/enum-method-overriding) for example.
2. Many people argue that `toString` is intended either for really obvious implementations, otherwise only for debugging. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762406/tostring-for-debugging-or-for-humans) for a good elaboration.) My recommendation: Come up with a more descriptive method name and don't reuse `toString` just for convenience.

**Update:** Zooming out from Java semantics a bit: This logic belongs to the view and not the model, as pointed out by BalusC in the comments below.

Comment: Overriding on a per-value basis isn't needed here - it would be cleaner just to private the message name in a constructor, store it in a field, then use it in a single implementation.

Comment: 1. What do you mean I can override toString for each case? Don't you mean toString(StatisticItems), do you?

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. Answer updated. user3663882, see link on item 1.2.

Comment: More elegant would be to completely move the localization from the model to the view. This is very definitely not model's responsibility.

Comment: @BalusC, I didn't think of that aspect, but I agree to 100%. Added a sentence at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure all of that complex logic is done once only at initialise time.

```
public enum StatisticItems {

    MESSAGES("messages"),
    VIEWS("views");
    final String asString;

    StatisticItems(String localised) {
        asString = getLocalizedMsg(localised + ".title");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return asString;
    }

    private static String BUNDLE_NAME = "messages";
    private static final Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale);

    private static String getLocalizedMsg(String key) {
        String resourceString;
        try {
            resourceString = bundle.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return key;
        }

        if (arguments == null) {
            return resourceString;
        }
        MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat(resourceString, locale);
        return format.format(arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's desirable to put all the complex logic which in this case includes loading ResourceBundles in costructors (let alone enum constructors, considering they are executed upon class loading). See for instance [Is doing a lot in constructors bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048515/is-doing-a-lot-in-constructors-bad).

Comment: @aioobe - If that seems a little too heavyweight there are various mechanisms to do it later such as [Multiton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18149547/823393)s.

Comment: Oh please no. Locale is in this particular context HTTP request / JSF view based, which is very definitely not application wide. In the future, please actually test the code yourself before doing off as an answer.

Comment: @BalusC - That code was copied from OP. All I did was make it `static final`. But I agree that locale should come from context.

Comment: Uh? OP did it right on a threadlocal basis, yet you made it a constant and introduced a potential NPE.