# Is it ok to add toString() to ease debugging?

Tags: java, tostring

I work a lot in IntelliJ and it can be quite convenient to have classes having their own toString() (the generated one in IntelliJ works fine) so you can see something more informative than MyClass@1345 when trying to figure out what something is.

My question is: Is that ok? I am adding code that has no business value and doesn't affect my test cases or the execution of my software (I am not using toString() for anything more than debugging). Still, it is a part of my process. What is correct here?

Comment: Use it while debugging, remove it before committing?

Comment: i prefer to override that method in every class even if i never use it

Comment: This is an opinion question, so it will likely be closed, since this site is for questions with a clear answer. Personally, I see no issue with adding toString methods to all classes. In fact, I think it is good practice to do so.

Comment: Use the actual  debugger instead of printing

Comment: What's wrong with code that's only used for debugging? By similar reasoning, unit-tests should be forbidden as they add no "business value". You value is that the code is easier to debug and thus has fewer bugs.

Comment: @tobias_k The point is to have that "debugging only" responsibility **within** your production code. Test cases are NOT part of the product.

Comment: That's perfect. Many JDK classes have `toString()` implementations clearly targeted at convenience of debugging. For some best-practice examples see the  `toString()` implementations in `java.util.AbstractCollection`, `java.util.AbstractMap`, `java.util.EventObject`, `java.awt.Component`, `java.awt.Color`, `java.awt.IndexColorModel`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762406/tostring-for-debugging-or-for-humans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `toString()` method is mainly designed as a debugging purpose method.

Except some exceptional cases, you should favor its use for debug purposes and not to display information to the clients as client needs may happen to be different or be the same as the `toString()` method today but could be different tomorrow.

From the `toString()` javadoc, you can read :

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

The parts that matter for your are :

> The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read.

and

> It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

You said that :

> Still, it is a part of my process. What is correct here?

Good thing : the specification recommends it.

Comment: Nice one. And again, thanks for leaving some things out so I could write up my 2 cent as well ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I hesitated to discuss also about robustness and performance concerns. Not a so bad thing finally as you have relieved me from it ;-)

Comment: I couldn't have gotten a better reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the excellent points by davidxxx, the following things apply:

- *Consistency* matters. People working with your code should *not* be surprised by what is happening within your classes. So either "all/most" classes @override `toString()` using similar implementations - or "none" does that.
- Thus: make sure everybody agrees if/how to implement `toString()`
- Specifically ensure that your `toString()` implementation is **robust**

Meaning: you absolutely have to avoid that your implementation throws any exception (for example a NPE because you happen to do `someString + fieldX.name()` for some fieldX that might be null).

You also have to avoid creating an "expensive" implementation (for example code that does a "deep dive" into some database to return a value from there).

2 cent of personal opinion: I find `toString()` to be of great value when debugging things; but I also have seen real performance impacts by *toString() too expensive*. Thing is: you have no idea how often some trace code might be calling `toString()` on your objects; so you better make sure it returns *quickly*.

Comment: Robustness is indeed a very important point. With JPA, it may create a disaster even. Nice adding.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) explain the function of this method:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

As you see, they don't specify a perticular use for this method or discourage you from using it for debuging, but they only state what it is expected to do and also recomend implementing this method in subclasses of Object.

Therefore strictly speaking how you use this method is up to you. In the university course i am taking, overwriting the toString method is required for some tasks and in some cases we are asked to use it to demonstrate debuging.

Answer (score -1):

It is perfectly OK and even a good idea. Most classes don't specify the content of toString so it's not wise to use it for logic (the content may change in a future version of the class). But some classes do, for example StringBuilder. And then it is also OK to use the return value for logic.

So for your own classes you may even opt to specify the content and use (and let your users use) the return value for logic.